# How to rotate a cell of sprite sheet?

Tags: xna, c#

I can draw an animated sprite sheet without problems.
But when it comes to rotation, the single cell (which gets drawn) rotates around the center of the whole sheet.

How can I get my cell to rotate around its own center?
This is what I found on the internet:

> Copy the current frame to a buffer, rotate the buffer, then copy the
>   buffer to the screen.
>   [Source](http://www.newgrounds.com/bbs/topic/1306691)

But I don't know what this means.

Answer (score 2):

Just rotate the *polygon* that the sprite is being rendered to.  You do not have to (and should not) rotate the *actual sprite texels* (unless you have a specific reason for doing so, which you didn't elaborate in your question).

Comment: I have no idea how to do that with sprites

Comment: Rotation angle is in one of the [SpriteBatch.Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx) overloads [(this one)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433992.aspx).  [See also here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203869.aspx)